# Can a normal variable hold the memory address for some other variable in C++?

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a = 5;
    int *b = &a;
    cout << b;
}
```

This outputs the address of `a`, so like `012FF86C` or something, and basically this is a string, right?

I watched some videos about pointers, and people said pointers are just a variable that hold an int value (memory address), but what about the `F`'s and the `C`'s?

Anyways, that's not the real question here. Basically, `012FF86C` is a string right, so why can't something like this work?

```cpp
string c = b;
```

I just get an error if I do that, but why?

Comment: `b` isn't a string, `cout` just "prints" pointers in that format (hexadecimal notation). The same way `cout << a` would print "5", but doesn't mean `a` is a string.

Comment: Not a string, an integer, printed in hexadecimal. Not necessarily an `int` though, it might have more bits than an `int`.

Answer (score 3):

> So this outputted the address of a so like 012FF86C or something and basically this is a string right?

No, it is not a string.  It's a number.  Printed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), as memory addresses often are.

A pointer holds a memory address, and memory addresses are numbers.
The number you printed identifies the address stored in your pointer.

> but what about the f's and the c's?

Hexadecimal uses digits 0-9 and letters a-f.

> Anyways that's not the real question here basically 012FF86C is a string right so why can't something like this work?  I just get an error if I do that but why?

Because `b` is a `int*`, not a string.

Comment: in this notation should the string be octal?

Answer (score 0):

b isn't a string, but a pointer to an int, so you can't assign them. Variables are strictly typed in C++. However, you can use a conversion function like:

```
string c = to_string(*b); // IDK, if just plain b will work, never tested
```

You already have the `#include <string>` and `using namespace std;`

---

Someone commented that you wanted address ...

Could do something like:

```
template <class T>
string to_string(T* p)
{
    return to_string((uintptr_t) p); // on visual c++, probably UINT_PTR instead of uintptr_t
}
```

and then in main

```
string c = to_string(b);
```

But that doesn't print in hexadecimal ...

Seemingly the simplest one line is:

```
cout << std::hex << (uintptr_t) b << endl;
```

Comment: Your code does `c = "5"`, and OP seemingly wants to have the hex pointer value in a string.

Answer (score 0):

Well, people have already pointed out that the address is actually a number not a string. But if you are still wondering about the question from the title "Can a normal variable hold the memory address for some other variable in C++?", I can hopefully give an answer since it seems nobody has talked about it yet.
Most modern operating system are 64bits now, so I'll assume that you are using a 64bits OS as well. In your 64bits OS, a memory address is stored as an unsigned 64bits integer or in C++

```
std::uint64_t / unsigned long.
```

So, you can reinterpret_cast/C style cast any pointer into unsigned 64bits integer and store it's address in a normal integer number.

```
float x = 8.9f;
std::uint64_t ptr = reinterpret_cast<std::uint64_t>(&x);
```

You need to reinterpret_cast it into appropriate pointer type again, if you want to use the address as a pointer.
This might be useful to do pointer arithmetics in bytes instead of using char*.

Answer (score 0):

`012FF86C` is value of `b` represented in hex
`b` is a pointer holds address of `a`
and you can't

```
string c = b; // unless b is of type string
```

but you can

```
string c = "b";
```

and also

```
int a = 0x012FCB59;  // hex representation
```